# Oracle SQL Constraint where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, where-clause, clause

I have the table Tester on oracle with the following columns:

- TesterID
- TesterName
- IsDefault
- Application_ID

TesterID is the primary key. 
Now I want that there can only be one Default Tester, which means only one Tester can have the calues IsDefault =Y at an ApplicationID.

I tried it with a constraint:

```
alter table Tester add constraint Tester_ISDEFAULT UNIQUE(IsDefault,Application_ID);
```

Is it possible to make the unique key on where isdefault= Y?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not with a `UNIQUE` constraint. However, you can use a `UNIQUE INDEX` instead:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ApplicationId_Default_Y ON tester (
  CASE WHEN IsDefault = 'Y'
       THEN ApplicationId
       ELSE NULL
  END
);
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8e6af)**.

Comment: Hello, It works, but I don't know how. You make the IsDefault to an index? What means then applicationid and else null?

Comment: Basically, when `IsDefault = 'Y'`, you store its application id in the index. Thus, since it's a *unique* index, if you try to insert again the same application id in the index with `IsDefault = Y`, it will throw an exception (because that application id was already in the index).

Comment: Just expanding Joao's explanation - this is usually called a "function-based index". It takes advantage of the fact that if the entire key is NULL, Oracle does not store anything in the index; so this index only stores ApplicationId when IsDefault = 'Y'. Furthermore, it's a unique index, so it guarantees that there will only be one row for any given ApplicationId where IsDefault = 'Y'.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a function-based unique index, not a constraint as such:

```
create unique index tester_isdefault on tester 
  (case when isdefault='Y' then application_id end);
```

Since Oracle doesn't created index entries for keys that are all null, only rows where isdefault='Y' will appear in the index.

Answer (score 0):

That constraint won't work as it would mean you can only have two rows for each Application_ID - one with IsDefault=0 and the other with IsDefault=1.

You could enforce this logic with a trigger. Or, why not just enforce it in your application logic?

Comment: using the trigger you face with mutation error else you have to invent kind of trick to defeat it. so unique FBI

Answer (score 0):

create unique index tester_ui_1 on tester(decode(is_default, 'Y', 0, tester_id), application_id)